# Как отобразить xml Report как результат выполнения nunt теста в Visual Studio 2019

Tags: c#, test-automation, nunit

Для выполнения комплексных тестов возникла такая задача.

1. Необходимо в базе данных сформировать тестовый сценарий.
2. Запустить тест в браузере (testCafe).
3. После завершения теста очистить тестовый сценарий.
4. Отобразить сформированный testCafe xml report (в формате nunit) как
       результат прохождения теста.

Вопрос вызывает 4 пункт. Я могу конечно в коде теста  прочесть результат  и выбросить исключение если тест не прошел. Но тест включает множество шагов и хотелось бы наглядно видеть что пошло не так.

Comment: Приведите конкретный пример как вы делаете 3 первых шага.

Comment: код привести не могу ( он на работе а там нильзя!) ,но на пальцах . В коде теста Nunit: 1)делаю инсерты 2) через Process запускаю node.exe c пускачем тестов в параметрах 3)жду завершения

Comment: код привести не могу ( он достаточно большой и на работе, а там нельзя) ,но на пальцах . 
В коде теста Nunit: </br>

1)делаю инсерты в базу </br>

2) через Process запускаю node.exe c пускачем тестов в параметрах </br>

3)жду завершения. </br>

4) удаляю то что инсертил </br>

5) анализирую отчет XML ( в виде файла ) </br>

Comment: Ну, напишите консольную утилиту, которая будет читать xml отчет и преобразовывать его в html файл.

Comment: и куда мне этот html? Конечная цель что бы это было результатом прохождения тестов